# bootstrap power law distribution with customize xmin

Tags: r, power-law, goodness-of-fit

I have a data series, where fitting power law distribution with R to data with following code I obtained alpha=1.97 and xmin=0.15.
pl_m= conpl$new(data)
est = estimate_xmin(pl_m)
when I run bootstrap to test the power law hypothesis by the bs_p = bootstrap_p(pl_m) function,the function provide p-value of the given xmin that was obtained from pl_m= conpl$new(S),(here xmin=0.15).
But based on Hill plot I found another point estimate for alpha(2.12) and xmin=0.44. Now using bootstrap_p how can I find the corresponding p-value for xmin=0.44, alpha=2.12?

I need to now the corresponding p-value of point estimate alpha and xmin which obtained visually from Hill plot.

Comment: Please make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and include any data you have and any code you've written so far.